# style tag relative path issue with ejs

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

Probably a real obvious issue here that I'm just missing.

my node application has a layout.ejs which contains a script tag

ex: `<link href="css/main-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">`

but when I visit a restful route for some "blog post" ex: posts/:someId

now the stylesheet is trying to locate itself with this path -> "posts/css/main-theme.css".

How do I make style and script tags search for their sources at the same path no matter the current url route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/` before path, like this

```
<link href="/css/main-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```